# Why does IIS give a broad "502.3 - Bad Gateway" error on circular constructors

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I do understand why the code *cant work*. I don't understand what technical reasons makes it so we don't get a more explicit error message.

While developing a netcore2 app I ended up making a circular reference with constructors. I mean that the constructor of an class A instantiated an other object of type B that would itself instantiate an object of type A and so on.

Here is a simple code snippet to reproduce the circular instantiation which throws a `StackOverflowException` on the [online compiler](http://rextester.com/JCZXD5796) I made that example on.

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        var b = new B();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        var b = new B();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();
    }
}
```

Surprisingly, instead of a stackoverflow exception it is a `502.3 - Bad Gateway` error that IIS gives me right before the application crashes, which doesn't give much information about the underlying problem. I expected a circular call like this to be a pattern easy enough to detect for it to be not only caught by a compiler, but even pin-pointed by VisualStudio 2017 or Resharper ultimate but nothing warned me about it.

[this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2017/08/04/asp-net-core-and-502-bad-gateway-response/) as well as [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/troubleshooting-application-request-routing/troubleshooting-502-errors-in-arr) seem to indicate that the problem could be a time-out but it seems unlikely since the application crashes in under two seconds.

I simply don't understand why there is no `CircularConstructionException` - this sounds easy enough to implement and even worse, why isn't IIS throwing a regular `StackOverflowException` like the online compiler ?

Comment: 502.3 is not an exception.  The actual exception may very well be a StackOverflowException. The 502.3 might not even be coming from IIS-- it could be coming from a proxy in between you and IIS.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but this is in local, in debug mode. For every other exception thrown I get an exception page with details. Why is the exception being hidden in this case only ? I kind of understand why the app crashes (no way to get out of the loop) but why is the StackOverflow or whatever exception is actually thrown hidden by IIS while it's in debug mode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the correct answer is that it is a design decision of C#. Whereas other exceptions are caught and wrapped in an exception page in your case, a `StackOverflowException` causes the process to terminate, which is reason to report a 502.3 response (reporting a connection failure).

---

From the MSDN page on [StackOverflowException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx)s:

> In prior versions of the .NET
>   Framework, your application could
>   catch a StackOverflowException object
>   (for example, to recover from
>   unbounded recursion). However, that
>   practice is currently **discouraged
>   because significant additional code is
>   required to reliably catch a stack
>   overflow exception and continue
>   program execution**.
>
> **Starting with the .NET Framework
>   version 2.0, a StackOverflowException
>   object cannot be caught by a try-catch
>   block and the corresponding process is
>   terminated by default.** Consequently,
>   users are advised to write their code
>   to detect and prevent a stack
>   overflow. For example, if your
>   application depends on recursion, use
>   a counter or a state condition to
>   terminate the recursive loop. Note
>   that an application that hosts the
>   common language runtime (CLR) can
>   specify that the CLR unload the
>   application domain where the stack
>   overflow exception occurs and let the
>   corresponding process continue. For
>   more information, see
>   ICLRPolicyManager Interface and
>   Hosting the Common Language Runtime.

Comment: Thank you very much for that pointer to the appropriate MSDN page. So it is indeed meant to be this way. I'll dig deeper towards the `ICLRPolicyManager` that the MSDN page mentions.

Answer (score 2):

> I simply don't understand why there is no CircularConstructionException - this sounds easy enough to implement

There's nothing illegal at runtime about an object instantiating another object, even of the same type.  The issue is that you haven't controlled the stack properly, so a `StackOverflowException` is actually appropriate.  In this case, arguably the issue could be detected by the compiler, but that's still not a runtime exception.

> and even worse, why isn't IIS throwing a regular StackOverflowException like the online compiler ?

IIS probably doesn't know why it died.  It creates a worker process to run your app; that process died due to the stack overflow.  The IIS host process then returned an error indicating that the worker process failed.  Maybe "Bad Gateway" isn't the most clear, but the IIS host doesn't know anything about the stack overflow.  It just knows that its worker process is not responding or dead.

Comment: Thank your for the further explanation about IIS's inner behaviour. I wish I could mark two answers as correct.

Answer (score -1):

This class calling itsef infinitive time and causing stack overflow

```
public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        var b = new B();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your statement is true, but this does not answer the question. Thank you for your time anyways :-)